# "creates a temporary which is freed while still in use" while trying to create a BufWriter

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

This code shows an error:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut writer = std::io::BufWriter::new(std::io::stdout().lock());
}
```

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src\main.rs:5:46
   |
5  |     let mut writer = std::io::BufWriter::new(std::io::stdout().lock());
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                                              |
   |                                              creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
...
12 | }
   | - borrow might be used here, when `writer` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `BufWriter`
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

This code works:

```rust
fn main() {
    let stdout = std::io::stdout();
    let mut writer = std::io::BufWriter::new(stdout.lock());
}
```

How is the borrow checker working here?

Answer (score 0):

[`Stdout::lock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdout.html#method.lock) returns a `StdoutLock` instance that borrows the `Stdout` that created it. In other words, the `StdoutLock` can last not longer than the `Stdout` that created it. As the compiler error suggests, the `Stdout` (created and returned by `std::io::stdout()`) is a temporary value which is freed right after use, invalidating the `Stdout` reference inside the `StdoutLock` (created by `std::io::stdout().lock()`). To prevent this from happening, you must give the `Stdout` returned by `std::io::stdout()` an explicit lifetime that outlasts the `StdoutLock` by binding it to a variable.